# expedia hotel booking process for onsite booking without using any deep linking concept

Tags: php, wordpress, api

I am using this GitHub code for hotel listing and hotel details section https://github.com/dyatlov/Expedia-PHP-API

for the booking process i am using this code:

```
$info = $expedia->getHotelInfo( $_REQUEST['hotelid'] );

echo '<pre>';
var_export( $info );

// book hotel
$expedia->set_method('POST');
$expedia->set_protocol('https://book.');
$result = $expedia->res( array(
    'hotelId' => $_REQUEST['hotelid'],
    'arrivalDate' => '7/27/2015',
    'departureDate' => '7/29/2015',
    'supplierType' => 'E',
    'rateKey' => '234be234234afd',
    'roomTypeCode' => 12345,
    'rateCode' => '123123',
    'chargeableRate' => '150.0',

    'room1' => 1,
    'room1FirstName' => 'John',
    'room1LastName' => 'Guest',
    'room1BedTypeId' => 1234,
    'room1SmokingPreference' => 'no',

    'email' => 'test@test.com',
    'firstName' => 'Tester',
    'lastName' => 'Tester',
    'homePhone' => '1234567',
    'workPhone' => '1234567',
    'creditCardType' => 'VI',
    'creditCardNumber' => '41111111111111111',
    'creditCardIdentifier' => '123',
    'creditCardExpirationMonth' => '05',
    'creditCardExpirationYear' => '2017',

    'address1' => 'travelnow',
    'city' => 'Moscow',
    'stateProvinceCode' => null,
    'countryCode' => 'RU',
    'postalCode' => '3357'
) );
```

but here I integrate this code in the WordPress and from the request URL i will get the hotel id now please tell me what is specified process to make the onsite booking for Expedia and how can get the confirmation and also cancel acknowledgement.I am doing all this job in the development mode.